# "The file is not a valid icon theme archive." - KDE Plasma 5 can't install one single icon theme

Tags: plasma-5, kde5

I have tried via the KDE Settings Icon theme installer & also the Manual way. I keep getting the  `The file is not a valid icon theme archive.` message. Not one single theme has worked so far. Anyone has a way? The default themes supplied are worthy of Windows NT.

Comment: What icon theme? How do you install it? What kind of file is the message referring?

Comment: Please read the question properly, thanks. I tried many themes.
> Not one single theme has worked so far

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out.

1. Download icon manually.
2. Extract the file to a temporary folder.
3. And move the folder (it should have an index.theme inside) to: `~/.local/share/icons` or `/usr/share/icons`
4. Enjoy.

There's a lot of misinformation on the Internet about the correct icon folder. And downloading icons using the System Settings is very unreliable.